# Compare choice with the choice of N trials before

Tags: r, lag

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
# set seed
set.seed(1234)

# load data
round<-rep(1:5,4)
players<-rep(1:2, c(10,10))
decs<-sample(1:3,20,replace=TRUE)
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(5,5)),2)
sameN_2<-c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)
gamematrix<-cbind(players,game,round,decs,sameN_2)
```

Now, I want to create a new variable, which will get a value of "1" if for each participant the choice made at the current trial in each game, is identical to the choice made *two trials ago* (for the respective participant in the respective game) and "0" otherwise.

This should result in the following vector in the example above (sameN_2) variable.

```
        players game round decs sameN_2
 [1,]       1    1     1    1       0
 [2,]       1    1     2    2       0
 [3,]       1    1     3    2       0
 [4,]       1    1     4    2       1
 [5,]       1    1     5    3       0
 [6,]       1    2     1    2       0
 [7,]       1    2     2    1       0
 [8,]       1    2     3    1       0
 [9,]       1    2     4    2       0
[10,]       1    2     5    2       0
[11,]       2    1     1    3       0
[12,]       2    1     2    2       1
[13,]       2    1     3    1       0
[14,]       2    1     4    3       0
[15,]       2    1     5    1       1
[16,]       2    2     1    3       0
[17,]       2    2     2    1       0
[18,]       2    2     3    1       0
[19,]       2    2     4    1       1
[20,]       2    2     5    1       1
```

Comment: Please define 'participant', 'trial', and 'the choice made'

Comment: @GuedesBF, What does it mean? This is a generic data (not a real one) - participants, is a participant in the experiment, trial - is the round number, and choice made - is the coding for choosing one of the alternatives

Comment: You did not even say this was the result of an experiment in which participants gave answers to a questionnaire. Nowhere in your question we can find info stating each `trial`was a `round`, and I still cant even from your explanation tell where is "the coding for choosing one of the alternatives" in your dataframe. Is it `decs`?

Comment: Are you sure your desired `sameN_2` vector is correct? There aren't two previous elements in the current group of row 12

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` to create previous values of `decs` -

```
library(dplyr)

gamematrix %>%
  group_by(players, game) %>%
  mutate(sameN_2 = as.integer(decs == lag(decs, 2, default = FALSE))) %>%
  ungroup

#   players  game round  decs sameN_2
#     <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>
# 1       1     1     1     1       0
# 2       1     1     2     2       0
# 3       1     1     3     2       0
# 4       1     1     4     2       1
# 5       1     1     5     3       0
# 6       1     2     1     2       0
# 7       1     2     2     1       0
# 8       1     2     3     1       0
# 9       1     2     4     2       0
#10       1     2     5     2       0
#11       2     1     1     3       0
#12       2     1     2     2       0
#13       2     1     3     1       0
#14       2     1     4     3       0
#15       2     1     5     1       1
#16       2     2     1     3       0
#17       2     2     2     1       0
#18       2     2     3     1       0
#19       2     2     4     1       1
#20       2     2     5     1       1
```

In `data.table` you may use `shift` for the same purpose -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(gamematrix)[, sameN_2 := as.integer(decs == shift(decs, 2, fill = FALSE)), .(players, game)]
```

**data**

`cbind` creates a matrix, using `data.frame` to create dataframe object.

```
gamematrix <- data.frame(players,game,round,decs,sameN_2)
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this. The OP should check why the results of this answer (row 12) differ from the row 12 in the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `base R` with `ave`

```
gamematrix$sameN_2 <- with(gamematrix, ave(decs, players, game,
    FUN = function(x) c(0, 0, head(x, -2) == tail(x, -2))))
```

#### data

```
gamematrix <- structure(list(players = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), game = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), round = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), decs = c(2, 2, 1, 
3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3), sameN_2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```